# Longest Word With *Only* Repeating Character Pairs

Tags: word, english, language, open-ended, letters

Inspired by and Opposite of: [Longest Word without repeating character-pairs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17448/9000)

The challenge is to find an English word in which every character pair appears at least twice. ("Word" does not include acronyms or proper names. Hyphenated words *are* included but the hyphen doesn't count as part of a pair.)

Bad word: `mama` contains the pair `ma` twice but `am` only once
Bad word: `aa` seems clever but still only has the pair once.
Good "word": `aaa` is not a word but it does contain its only pair `aa` twice.

Preference will be given to words found on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Here's a check method in Excel: Input the word in the cell `A1` and then input this formula somewhere else as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>: (`TRUE` = valid word, `FALSE` = invalid word)

```
=(SUM(LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($A$1),MID(UPPER($A$1),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,LEN($A$1)-1)),2),"")))/4)+1>=LEN($A$1)
```

I've been told this javascript function will perform the same check although I haven't used the language in *years* and can't verify:

```
function test(e){for(l=[],i=1;i<e.length;i++)p=e[i-1]+e[i],l.push(p);return l2=new Set(l),l.length/l2.size==2?!0:!1}
```

**NOTE:** The answers thus far and the scratches I tried to come up with were all of the form `[string][same string][first letter of string]`. I'd be interested in finding one of a different form although the longest of any form will be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Immediately thought of Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo...

Comment: muhnuhmuhnuh <shrug>

Comment: @MackTuesday Did you mean [muh nuh muh nuh](https://www.google.com/search?q=muhnuhmuhnuh)?

Comment: @EngineerToast  Yes. =)

Comment: FYI, your excel formula does not work. I tried it and the only valid string I could find was the empty one.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'd be interested if it fails for others. It works for me, to be sure. Are you entering it as an array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: Ahhhhh I thought you meant CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER on the _input_... haha, my mistake. ^^"

Comment: JavaScript function: `function test(e){for(l=[],i=1;i<e.length;i++)p=e[i-1]+e[i],l.push(p);return l2=new Set(l),l.length/l2.size==2?!0:!1}`

Comment: [Titin](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/fun/news/a444700/longest-word-has-189819-letters-takes-three-hours-to-pronounce.html#~phJlx4BBaqn4Uu) is not valid, since it contains only one x, so the upper limit is at 189,819 excluded.

Comment: Out of contest, there is latin TETEROROMAMANUNUDADATETELALATETE (though it should honestly be split into *te tero, Roma, date tela, latete!* and doesn't repeat the overlapping pair positions)

Comment: "Muhnuhmuhnuh" has only one "hm".

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Your code tests that, the list of character pairs is half the length of the list of unique character pairs, which I don't think accurately tests this puzzle.

Comment: @Bob Precisely. It tests if each of the character pairs appears exactly twice, as per the puzzle. It also works with all the suggestions people have come up with.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ The puzzle requires each pair to appear *at least* twice, not exactly twice. All the answers, though, have had them appear exactly twice.

Comment: @EngineerToast Ah, that is why. Something I might wish to work on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found a possible word, though it seems... invalid

11 letters

> kinnikinnik
>  It's on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kinnikinnick) as kinnikinnick, though it includes the above form in the "Also" section.

Comment: I think that things listed as "also" on Dictionary.com would be considered valid. That indicates that they are accepted spellings.

Comment: How in the world did you find that!?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: According to Dictionary.com, it is _'a mixture of bark, dried leaves, and sometimes tobacco, formerly smoked by the Indians and pioneers in the Ohio valley.'_

Comment: This is the longest valid word appearing in Ubuntu's `american-english-insane` dictionary, so I doubt it will be beaten.

Answer (score 35):

I think I can do 7 letters:

> ALFALFA

Which features the letter pairs:

> 'AL' twice, 'LF' twice, and 'FA' twice

Comment: Nice! I was sure that there wouldn't be any such words.

Comment: mark got the tick but you get +1 for a quick and popular answer.

Answer (score 10):

- anapanapa (9)
- sasararas (9)
- kinnikinnik (11)

These words are the longest I could find. Kudos to the [guy who found kinnikinnik](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17474/9000) first, though. 11 letters is crazy.

Comment: Does "anapanapa" have a meaning?

Comment: sasararas is nice since it's a not the a word on the form [string][string][first character of string]

Answer (score 7):

Here’s another seven letter word:

> ENTENTE, which is [on Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entente?s=t)

As with Bailey M’s answer, there are three pairs, each of which appears twice::

> EN, NT and TE

I found this by going through the Unix words list with a Python script ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/alexwlchan/973a270729f77c4acdaa)).

---

That threw up a few other words, but I can neither find them on Dictionary.com, nor indeed find any other definition or explanation for why they’re there:

> ANAPANAPA (9) – four pairs of two: AN, NA, AP, PA
>  DEEDEED (7) – three pairs of two: DE, EE, ED

Answer (score 5):

Another 11-letter word is **strumstrums**, although it doesn't exist at dictionary.com unfortunately.

According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strumstrum) the word *strumstrum* appeared in the 1913 edition of Webster's Dictionary, and refers to a type of musical instrument. The plural is strumstrums.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found using the [Enable word list](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt):

alfalfa
entente
sarsars
tzitzit

Answer (score 0):

By using the same word list as Golden Dragon and the regular expression

```
 ([a-zA-Z]{4})\1+ 
 #Match any group of four letters that occurs at least twice in a word
```

I was able to find

- lavalava
- mahimahi
- beriberi
- caracara
- chowchow
- couscous
- froufrou
- greegree
- guitguit
- kavakava

and hotshots which is of a little higher "quality".

These all have eight letters obviously. It is not so easy, to match words that consist of different repeating groups, though.

Comment: The problem with these is that the letter group in the middle of the world (for instance, 'al' for lavalava) is not matched anywhere else.

Comment: BUT if any of them are singular nouns, then putting an "s" on the end (e.g. "beriberis") *will* make it meet the criteria! I'll undo my downvote if you edit with this fix :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I don't think that would fix them unless the first letter of the word is "s" which would make the fifth letter of the word "s"

Comment: @MisterEman22 Um, yes - good point. That leaves us with things like "caracarac" and "greegreeg", and probably none of those are words :-(

Comment: Here is a different regexp that does not work.  (.NET flavor for arbitrary length lookaround)  `^(?:((?:.){2})(?:(?<=\1.*..)|(?=.*\1)))+$`

Comment: Well, "lavalaval" is pretty good: (adj.) resembling a lavalava.  Also a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Another 11 letter one:

> UNKULUNKULU

Not present on dictionary.com unfortunately, but thought it was interesting enough to add here.