# Longest Sentence Where Every Character Pair Repeats $n$ times

Tags: english, open-ended, letters

**BACKGROUND**

This is essentially a combination of two puzzles:
[Longest *Sentence* With Only Repeating Character Pairs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17531/9000) (which has been shown to be infinite)
[Longest sentence with each letter repeated n times](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/8223/9000) (which maxed out at $n=16$)

---

### CHALLENGE

**Form a grammatically correct sentence with $c$ alphabetic characters (`[A-Za-z]`)in which every letter *pair* appears *exactly $n$* times. Your score is $n\times c$. Maximize that score.**

Clarifications: (The example below is invalid and is only intended to assist in clarification.)

- Words can not be repeated but variations of a word do not count as a repetition. This includes plurals, possessives, contractions, etc. so long as it does not violate other clarifications. `Uni the Unicorn's eating the unicorn!` and `Bob's bobbing bobbed the bobber.` are OK but `Unicorns ate the unicorn's food.` is not OK as it violates the second clarification.
- Words count as a repetition if they match when converted to all uppercase and any non-letters are removed. Different definitions, punctuation, or capitalization does not prevent it counting as a repetition. `Buffalo buffalos buffalo bison.` (`Buffalo` "city" and `buffalo` "bully" are counted as a repitition.)
- Any non-letter (spaces, hyphens, apostrophes, etc.) should be stripped prior to analysis. The result will be just a string of letters. `UnitheUnicornseatingtheunicorns`
- Capitalization does not matter. Convert them all to uppercase if that helps. `UNITHEUNICORNSEATINGTHEUNICORNS`

The "purest" answers will also meet these conditions: (not required to be valid but somewhat more impressive)

- Every word appears on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)
- No proper nouns
- No acronyms or abbreviations

---

### CHECKING

Here are some check methods. I've written a verbose one in VBA. Corrections and submissions in other languages are most welcome.

**VBA**

Outputs the most common, highest value for $n$ along with a score and a list of any that do not match. (It's not golfed at all because I preferred accuracy and readability over compression.)
Example 1) Input: `Alfalfa`. Output: `n = 2, c = 7, Score = 14`
Example 2) Input: `Alfalfac`. Output: `n = 2: AC(1)`
Example 3) Input: `Uni Unicorns`. Output: `n = 1: UN(2), NI(2)`

```
Option Explicit
Function ValidateString(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sTemp As String, v As String
    Dim cValue As String, cCount As Long, cCountCount As Long
    Dim nValue As Long, nCount As Long, nList As String

    'Sanitize
    s = UCase(s)
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90:  sTemp = sTemp & Mid(s, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    s = sTemp

    'Find all n values
    For i = 1 To Len(s) - 1
        cValue = Mid(s, i, 2)
        cCount = 0
        For j = 1 To Len(s) - 1
            If Mid(s, j, 2) = cValue Then cCount = cCount + 1
        Next j
        nList = nList & "|" & cCount & "|"
    Next

    'Find largest, most common n value
    For i = 1 To Len(s) - 1
        cValue = Mid(s, i, 2)
        cCount = 0
        For j = 1 To Len(s) - 1
            If Mid(s, j, 2) = cValue Then cCount = cCount + 1
        Next j
        cCountCount = (Len(nList) - Len(Replace(nList, "|" & cCount & "|", ""))) / (2 + Len(cCount))
        If cCountCount > nCount Then nValue = cCount: nCount = cCountCount
        If cCountCount = nCount And cCount > nValue Then nValue = cCount
    Next

    'List any that don't match
    sTemp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s) - 1
        cValue = Mid(s, i, 2)
        cCount = 0
        For j = 1 To Len(s) - 1
            If Mid(s, j, 2) = cValue Then cCount = cCount + 1
        Next j
        cCountCount = (Len(nList) - Len(Replace(nList, "|" & cCount & "|", ""))) / (2 + Len(cCount))
        If cCountCount <> nCount And InStr(1, sTemp, cValue) = 0 Then sTemp = sTemp & cValue & " (" & cCount & "), "
    Next
    v = "n = " & nValue
    If sTemp = "" Then v = v & ", c = " & Len(s) & ", Score = " & nValue * Len(s)
    If sTemp <> "" Then v = v & ": " & Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 2)
    ValidateString = v
End Function
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to puzzlers, pay very close attention to letter pairs that cross words (like 'ea' in 'the apple'). That was what tripped up a lot of the answers in the previous letter pair puzzle.

Comment: Sometimes the code doesn't return the list of unmatching digraphs. When I input "tomato", it returns "n=2", and when I input "mad madam mimi" it returns "n=2".

Comment: @mmking When I put in "tomato" I get `n = 1: TO(2)`. For "mad madam mimi" I get `n = 2: DM(1), DA(1), AM(1), MM(1), IM(1)`. Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: That's weird. I put in in a vb.net console application on VS 2013 to run it, but I don't think there should be a difference.

Comment: @mmking I'm running it in VBA within Excel. I'm not sure of the differences between VB and VBA. It sounds like it's returning as soon as `ValidateString` has a value. I'll setup another temp value and we can see if that helps.

Comment: Does the WHOLE sentence consist of pairs?

Comment: @warspyking A pair is a letter and the next letter in the sentence. If the sentence has $x$ letters, then it has $x-1$ pairs. For this challenge, every pair must appear an equal number of times.

Comment: So say for example "Seen" was a sentence, the pairs would be "se", "ee", and "en"?

Comment: @warspyking That's correct. See the other two puzzles ([1](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17471/9000), [2](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17531/9000)) for more examples. These are the two puzzles that I posted previously about letter pairs.

Comment: 1 of the other two puzzles is mine lol, I already know how it worked

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### n = 8, c = 17, Score = 136

Rather than trying to maximize c, I am instead attempting to maximize n.

To that end:

> Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo, bob!

This is an imperative statement, commanding the main character from
[this anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobobo-bo_Bo-bobo) to commence [attempting to extract apples from a bucket of water using only his teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_bobbing).

8 pairs * 17 characters = 136

I feel like one could torture a few more 'bo's in there, but I think this is fine for what is essentially a joke answer. =P

Comment: I finally gave the tick for the highest score with a grammatically correct sentence.

Answer (score 4):

### n = 2, c = 19, Score = 38

OK, here's one to get the ball rolling:

**She's going to put her money on the old sailors**:

> SHE'LL BACK SHELLBACKS.

Comment: It's valid so far as I can tell. It's in the familiar format `[string][string][left(string,1)]`, which makes sense. I'm going to switch the score to be $n\times c$ where $c$ is the alpha characters in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

### n = $\infty$: OB($\infty-1$)      (Invalid per clarification 1)

Without rules the hilarious near answer is:

> Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo
>  buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo ...
>  on to infinity as there are no two'fer character pairs in buffalo so each pair
>  gets repeated n times where n is the number of words. there is punctuation to
>  deal with, but buffalo infinitum is a sentence.

A number of flaws follow if you actually read the rules.

Comment: I believe that 'OB' repeats one fewer times than the rest of the letter pairs.

Comment: And the OP said that you can't use the same word more than once.

Comment: Excellent point, did not read the instructions closely, now if only B was a stand alone word that grammatically fit...

Answer (score 0):

### n = 3, c = 19, Score = 57

If abbreviations are okay the:

> Adder's adder sadder SA

Meaning:

> The sadder SA of the Adder's adder. Or maybe. The SA of Adder that was sadder by and adder. I have no idea either.

Comment: *The sadder SA of the Adder's adder.* doesn't seem like a valid grammatical construct. This is merely the subject, without a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

### n = 3, c = 13, Score = 39

A grammatically correct, but absolutely nonsense sentence.

> Seats eat sea TS.

The explanation

> Chairs consume top secrets of the sea. (To clarify, [Dictionary.com lists the definition of TS as an abbreviation.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ts?s=t))

Comment: It's an expansion on the format: `[string][string][string][left(string,1)]`. I'm beginning to suspect they might all be that way. I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

### n = 7, c = 29, score = 203

Inspired by [my first answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17603/12700), here's another with a better value of n and much better score. *Be warned, you are about to reveal yet another nonsensical sentence that stays on the right side of the grammar line...*

> Seats eat sea TS, eats, Ea, TSE at SE ATS.

The explanation

> Chairs consume top secrets of the sea, food, [the Akkadian god of wisdom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/EA?s=t), the [Toronto Stock Exchange](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/TSE?s=t) (sorry Canada) at the South Eastern outpost of the [Auxiliary Territorial Service](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ATS?s=t).

Comment: I believe according to clarification #2, "seats" and "seat's" are counted as repeated words.

Comment: @VictorHenry: Not quite. The punctuation doesn't vary it as different proper nouns, because the second use of seat's is of the possessive form. This is valid according to clarification #1.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. I think, actually, the clarifications directly contradict each other in this case. "Words count as a repetition if they match when converted to all uppercase and any non-letters are removed" is a direct contradiction of the possessives and contractions rule from the first clarification.

Comment: @VictorHenry They did contradict. I have revised it to remove it, I hope.

Comment: I would argue that you need an `and` in that list o' yours.

Comment: @EngineerToast: Then I would quote [this article](http://www.virtualsalt.com/rhetoric.htm#Asyndeton) which explains how the omitted and is valid in a sentence. It's a literary device, used often in story telling.